# Lightswitch Users & Roles & ApplicationDatabase

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch

I can see that the internal database for lightswitch is called "ApplicationDatabase" and if you look inside the directory structure outside of Vs10 the database is in the bin folder.

Is anyone aware of how I would extend the users and roles function in lightswitch? I need to be able to associate which "store" a user belongs to so that when they authenticate I can pass in the store parameter to the queries I have created.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

LightSwitch uses the same Membership framework that is used by ASP.NET and other Microsoft technologies. I've written [this blog post](http://traf-o-data.blogspot.com/2011/08/linking-lightswitch-data-to-logged-in.html) on the topic of how to link data to user logins; this should hopefully get you started on this topic.

Comment: Paul, thanks for your blog post. That is just what the doctor ordered!

Comment: One question if you have time to answer. I don't know that I entirely understand what is happening in this code. I see that input "pretend" users. If I run my app in debug mode, I see the list of pretend users but I cannot go add a new user from the user screen and have it show up in the list?

Comment: I found the pretend users convenient in my own work, but if you prefer to enable SecurityAdministration and add users during debug, you just have to remove everything between "#if DEBUG" and "#else" and then remove the directive "#endif" in the GetUsers() function